# User state custom pages - best way to assemble in php

Tags: php, html

I have a jqtouch website depending on if someone is logged in or not the pages change. At the moment I have a pretty ugly solution....

```
 function page1()
 {
     $page1 = '<div>.........</div>';
     return $page1;
 }

 function page2()
 {
     $page2 = '<div>.........</div>';
     return $page2;
 }

 function page3()
 {
     $page3 = '<div>.........</div>';
     return page3();
 }
```

etc....

to load the page I do the following

```
 echo page1() . page2() . page3();
```

or

```
 echo page1() . page3();
```

Depending on what the user state is.

I need to mix and match pages so I have all the pages in one main page and only really want to run the sql withing those pages should they be needed.

effectively I have a stack of cards and I want to put them together in various ways with out disturbing the unrequired ones.

How would you assemble the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use templates:

In `page1.php`

```
<div>You are logged in!</div>
include_once("common2.php");
<div>Do you want to logout?</div>
```

In `page2.php`

```
<div>Please login first!/div>
include_once("common2.php");
<div><a href="#">Login Here</a></div>
```

In `common.php`

```
<div>This is common to all pages</div>
```

In `common2.php`

```
<div>
  This is common to all pages but 
  it appears in the middle of the content of page1 and page 2
</div>
```

Then in your `gateway` page you do this:

```
include_once("common.tpl");

if($userIsLoggedIn)
{
  include_once("page1.tpl");
}
else
{
  include_once("page2.tpl");
}
```

Comment: This removes my flexibility a bit. If page1.tpl and page2.tpl had a common div and I made a change to one I would have to change the other. Which wouldn't be a biggie if I didn't have multiple page types. Could easily change one and forget about the other.

Comment: Then use `include`s in those pages as well. Just to be sure, use `.php` extensions and not `.tpl`. I have edited my answer to demonstrate this

Comment: I broke all the pages into separate pages. Then included each as required. Nice tidy solution thx.